# Parse true and false values on a JSON string using NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:

Tags: objective-c, json, nsjsonserialization

I'm developing an iOS 5 and above application with latest SDK.

I have to parse this JSON:

```
{"GetHoroscope":false,"GetQuoteOfTheDay":false, ... }
```

To do it, I have this code:

```
- (NSDictionary*)getDictionaryFromNSData:(NSData*)jsonData
{
    NSError* error = nil;
    id jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization
                     JSONObjectWithData:jsonData
                     options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments
                     error:&error];
    if ((jsonObject != nil) && (error == nil))
    {
        NSLog(@"Successfully deserialized...");
        if ([jsonObject isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
        {
            NSDictionary* deserializedDictionary = (NSDictionary *)jsonObject;
            NSLog(@"Dersialized JSON Dictionary = %@", deserializedDictionary);

            return deserializedDictionary;
        }
    }

    return nil;
}
```

But I have a problem with `boolean` values. When I check `deserializedDictionary` I see that  `GetHoroscope` and `GetQuoteOfTheDay` values are null.

**Do I need to do something special with boolean values?**

Comment: You kinda need to show us the code you're using to attempt to reference these values.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

JSON "true" and "false" values are stored as `NSNumber` objects, so the following
should work:

```
BOOL b = [deserializedDictionary[@"GetHoroscope"] boolValue];
```